# How do I configure Tridion Pages with Extension XML to get published to file system and rest to Broker DB?

Tags: tridion

I am trying to configure cd_storage_conf file to get the pages with extension XML to get  published to file system. I am not sure what value should I give for typeMapping attribute in Item node to enable this configuration. Can anyone help?

Comment: Moving forward please ask Tridion questions on the dedicated Tridion site: tridion.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

Add an itemType element with a typeMapping of "Page" and an itemExtension attribute of ".xml" to your cd_storage_conf.xml. Be sure to do this for both your deployer and your application so that your configurations match

From the [online documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent) (login required): [Configuring content storage](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_005JJFGGGD8858699HHFHJF)

> You can store specific types of Pages (that is, Web pages with
>   specific file extensions) in a different storage medium. To do this,
>   insert an Item element inside the ItemTypes element:
>
> ```
> <Item typeMapping="Page" itemExtension=".Jsp" cached="CACHE_BEHAVIOR" storageId="STORAGE_ID" />
> ```